# Black screen and flashing underscore while installing off a usb (10.10) and all other higher versions

Tags: installation, boot, 10.10, usb, live-usb

Downloaded the .iso for 10.10 , ll.10, 12.04 and 12.10. i have then tried every single one of these versions on a usb (yes i did create the usb correctly (i have done this before)) but when i restart my mac and hold alt and boot into the liveusb (which it calls windows) it loads to a black screen with underscore. the only thing i can do from this is force shutdown. help me please!

Answer (score 0):

This link can probably help you:
[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Try with `nomodeset` and if that don't work add `acpi=off` and `noapic`

Comment: no help what-so-ever